# How do I send some data (eg. a String) from my Activity to a Service ...in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

Usually, I putExtra inside an Intent to transfer stuff between Activities.

But it seems like I can't do this with a Service?

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

That doesn't work for a android Service.  How do I send a string from an Activity to a Service then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way as you did with the `Activity`. You will get the `Intent` in the `onStart()` callback method, which you would need to override. That will be called whenever a client calls `startService()` for your `Service`, supplying the `Intent` in question.